# Annotate django-taggit tags attached to specific object

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset, django-taggit

I have an object that is tagged using [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit).  If I wanted to get a list of all the tags attached to this object, I would follow the documentation like so:

```
apple = Food.objects.create(name="apple")
apple.tags.add("red", "green", "delicious")
apple.tags.all()
```

If I wanted to know how many Food objects were attached to each tag in existence, I would do the following:

```
Tag.objects.all().annotate(food_count=Count('food'))
```

If I wanted to get a count of all of the food items attached *only* to the tags that are attached to 'apple', I could do the following:

```
apple = Food.objects.create(name="apple")
apple.tags.add("red", "green", "delicious")
apple.tags.all().annotate(food_count=Count('food'))
```

Ok, so for my question.  Let's say my Food model has a field with a flag:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique = True)
    healthy_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How can I get a count of all of the *healthy* foods attached *only* to the tags that are attached to 'apple' (where a healthy food is denoted by healthy_flag = 1)?  Basically, for every 'apple' tag, how many healthy foods share that tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations).

```
apple.tags.all().annotate(food_count=Count('food')).filter(food__health_flag = True)
```